# How to calculate maximum discharge rate of a battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I am not an electric engineer. I just want to know how many devices (aircon) I can use safely with my new lithium battery.

We bought a new lithium battery 200ah, 48v. With 6kw inverter.

Initially we use it for 2 **(1hp aircons)** at the same time. But, I want to use **3 (1hp aircons)** at the same time. Side-note we also open 5 or 6 light bulbs.

Will it hurt the battery? How can I calculate maximum discharge rate of a battery without damaging it?

Comment: It's not the sort of thing that you 'calculate', it should be stated on the side of the battery. If you bought the battery and inverter as a pair, then I would expect the battery to support the max inverter output (6 kW) without damage.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** calculate the safe discharge rate. Batteries are designed for different things, like storing the most energy per weight, or being able to supply the most current per weight. Or something in the middle.

Since these two goals conflict, batteries differ in how much current they can supply by large factors. Only the manufacturer can tell you for what currents they've designed and tested their cells.

Effectively, you could do the same tests on your batteries, but there's no guaranteed way to not damage them while doing that. So that's not what you want.

So, really, ask the supplier of your batteries how much current you can draw. Note that slight overcurrent might just reduce capacity and life of your battery, but significant overcurrent might overheat your battery and potentially make it fail in explosive ways.